# Colored row not showing demarcated cells

Tags: tables, color, colortbl

I am having multiple issues while generating tables in LaTeX. I need to have the output in form of a pdf.

The first issue is that the top row which is colored, the cells are not being demarcated ie the vertical rows are missing. Take a look below

[image]
The code for the table is given below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
\geometry{a4paper,tmargin=3.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm, lmargin=1.5cm, rmargin=1.5cm, headheight=3em, headsep=1.5cm, footskip=1cm} 
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{mColor1}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
\normalsize
\centering
\def\arraystretch{1.5}% 

\begin{tabular}{|p{\dimexpr.25\textwidth} | p{\dimexpr.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep} | p{\dimexpr.15\textwidth-2\tabcolsep} |p{\dimexpr.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{mColor1}
\textbf{\ Company Name \ } & \textbf{\ CIN/FCRN \ }  & \textbf{\ Share \% \ } & \textbf{\ Type of Company \ } \\   
\hline
  Kingfisher Air Pvt. Ltd.&  U72200KA2008PTC048012&  23 & Manufacturing \\
 \hline
  Tata Sky Air Pvt. Ltd.&  L98700KA2008PTC048012&  34  & Financial and Banking \\
 \hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Also the table created looks different in different PDF viewer (Adobe, Foxit, Google PDF Viewer) and more importantly the table looks different within the same program at different resolution.

Above table at 150%
[image]

Answer (score 3):

That is a known viewer issue. You can partially get rid of this by increasing the rule width by `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}`, for example. Also, `\arraystretch` is better changed via `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` rather than `\def{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\geometry{a4paper,tmargin=3.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm, lmargin=1.5cm, rmargin=1.5cm, headheight=3em, headsep=1.5cm, footskip=1cm} 
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{mColor1}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}

\begin{document}    

\begin{table}[h!]
\normalsize
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% 
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}% 
\begin{tabular}{|p{\dimexpr.25\textwidth} | p{\dimexpr.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep} | p{\dimexpr.15\textwidth-2\tabcolsep} |p{\dimexpr.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{mColor1}
\textbf{\ Company Name \ } & \textbf{\ CIN/FCRN \ }  & \textbf{\ Share \% \ } & \textbf{\ Type of Company \ } \\   
\hline
  Kingfisher Air Pvt. Ltd.&  U72200KA2008PTC048012&  23 & Manufacturing \\
 \hline
  Tata Sky Air Pvt. Ltd.&  L98700KA2008PTC048012&  34  & Financial and Banking \\
 \hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This is at `150%` in Adobe Reader, but other viewers show fewer artifacts.

[image]

Even better is using `booktabs`. In this case, the table shows no atifacts at all zoom levels, see this at `100%` (without changing the `rulewidth`):

[image]

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\normalsize
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% 
\begin{tabular}{p{\dimexpr.25\textwidth}  p{\dimexpr.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}  p{\dimexpr.15\textwidth-2\tabcolsep} p{\dimexpr.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\toprule
\rowcolor{mColor1}
\textbf{Company Name} & \textbf{CIN/FCRN}  & \textbf{Share \%} & \textbf{Type of Company} \\   
\midrule
  Kingfisher Air Pvt. Ltd.&  U72200KA2008PTC048012&  23 & Manufacturing \\
 \midrule
  Tata Sky Air Pvt. Ltd.&  L98700KA2008PTC048012&  34  & Financial and Banking \\
 \bottomrule 
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

Answer (score 3):

The package `nicematrix`, with its environment `{NiceTabular}`, has been dedicated to avoid that kind of problem. The rules won't seem to disappear, whatever PDF viewer you use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,tmargin=3.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm, lmargin=1.5cm, rmargin=1.5cm, headheight=3em, headsep=1.5cm, footskip=1cm} 
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\normalsize
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{NiceTabular}{X[25]X[30]X[15]X[30]}[hvlines]
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor[rgb]{0.9,0.9,0.9}{1}
\Body
  \RowStyle[bold]{}
  \ Company Name \  & \ CIN/FCRN \   & \ Share \% \  & \ Type of Company \  \\   
  Kingfisher Air Pvt. Ltd.&  U72200KA2008PTC048012&  23 & Manufacturing \\
  Tata Sky Air Pvt. Ltd.&  L98700KA2008PTC048012&  34  & Financial and Banking \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: I have found now https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610709/multiple-curly-brackets-aligned-one-part-to-the-right-and-the-other-to-the-left#comment1527629_610709. Now I remove my first comment.

Answer (score 2):

With use of the `tabularray` package you will get satisfactory result:

[image]

Code for table is short and clean:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, 
            vmargin={3.5cm, 2.5cm}, hmargin={1.5cm, 1.5cm}, 
            headheight=3em, headsep=1.5cm, footskip=1cm
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage[xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{colspec={X[2.5,l]X[3,l]X[1.5,l]X[3,l]},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries, bg=gray9},
             rowsep=3pt,
             hlines, vlines,
             }
Company Name                & CIN/FCRN              & Share \%  & Type of Company       \\
Kingfisher Air Pvt. Ltd.    & U72200KA2008PTC048012 & 23        & Manufacturing         \\
  Tata Sky Air Pvt. Ltd.    & L98700KA2008PTC048012 & 34        & Financial and Banking \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```