# Multiple curly brackets aligned one part to the right and the other to the left

Tags: align, cases, braces

How to draw such a diagram to show how the singularities are classified?

[image]

[image]

Incorrect demonstration:

[image]

Comment: Nested cases might do the job: https://ctan.org/pkg/cases?lang=en. See e.g. here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464189/nested-cases-alignment-and-numbering.

Comment: Sorry, can you please illucidate a little what you mean by "incorrect demonstration"? If you have some Latex code, which generated it, can you please provide it? Thanks

Comment: You prove to use cascade package

Comment: @Sebastiano: Unfortunately, the package `cascade` can't to such construction (it does structures in the other sens). I will try to write a new version of `cascade` for that kind of problem.

Comment: @F.Pantigny You're great. I not know this problem. Thank you very much for your precious contribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you can do with the command `\Edacsac` of the package `cascade` (≥ 1.2 of 2021-08-23). `\Edacsac` is the word *cascade* written in reverse.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cascade}

\begin{document}

Singularity
\Edacsac
  {Elementary}
  {
    \Edacsac          
      {Non-degenerate Elementary}
      {\ShortEdacsac{Hyperbolic}{Non-Hyperbolic}}
      {Degenerate Elementary}
      {}
  }
  {Non-Elementary}
  {\ShortEdacsac{Nilpotent}{Higher order}}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

If you want alignment of the second-level braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cascade}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

Singularity
\Edacsac
  {\makebox[\widthof{Non-Elementary}][r]{Elementary}}
  {
    \Edacsac          
      {Non-degenerate Elementary}
      {\ShortEdacsac{Hyperbolic}{Non-Hyperbolic}}
      {Degenerate Elementary}
      {}
  }
  {Non-Elementary }
  {\ShortEdacsac{Nilpotent}{Higher order}}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Comment: To line up the second set of braces, as seems to be requested by the question, you can set "Elementary" flush right in a box the width of "Non-Elementary".

Comment: @barbara beeton: I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with a `tabular` and `\left`/`\right` commands with brackets.
Although, I had to put text inside an array so **my solution seems really ugly**.
I also used the `multirow` package to *merge* some cells and be able to do it as you wanted. Anyway, [the `multirow` package seems to have difficulties to vertically align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66599/204085) so I had to adjust with the `fixup`-parameter.

Additionally, I needed `amsmath` because I needed this to use `\left` and `\right` sequences.

Finally, here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l@{}l@{}l@{}l}
\multirow{3}{*}[-12pt]{Singularity} & \multirow{3}{*}[-8pt]{$\left\{\begin{array}{@{}r@{}} \text{Elementary}\\[27.5pt]\text{Non-elementary}\end{array}\right.$\vspace{1cm}} & \multirow{2}{*}{$\left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}} \text{Non-degenerate Elementary}\\\text{Degenerate Elementary}\end{array}\right.$} & $\left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}} \text{Hyperbolic}\\\text{Non-Hyperbolic}\end{array}\right.$  \\
 & & & \\
 & & $\left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}} \text{Nilpotent}\\\text{Higher order}\end{array}\right.$ &
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And here's how it looks:
[image: LaTeX ouput]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I hope to get the line alignment of each line as shown in Figure 2.